# Microsoft Graph Explorer $batch- Error message: 'Provided identifier is malformed - site id is not valid'

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

```
I'm trying to do a $batch (POST) request in Microsoft Graph Explorer with a simple 
request with only one GET operation:
```

'''
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$batch

```
{
"requests": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "method": "GET",
        "url": "/sites/{xxxxxx.sharepoint.com,a2460b71-0904-4476-a18b- 
               ce6ac77a1287,e0f4fd7b-b513-4d13-be7d-0f0e0b3baf4e}/lists/{8ea8962a- 
               e198-4a1b-a825-6da777887948}/items"
    }
  ]
}'
```

'''

However, getting an error response saying the 'site id is not valid'

```
"message": "Provided identifier is malformed - site id is not valid",
```

When I do a simple GET request using the MS Graph Explorer URL not using MS Graph $batch, on the same site and list, the siteId is the same as the one i'm trying to use in my $batch request, the siteId works fine and is the same one returned in 'parentReference' field

'''
"siteId": "xxxxxx.sharepoint.com,a2460b71-0904-4476-a18b-
ce6ac77a1287,e0f4fd7b-b513-4d13-be7d-0f0e0b3baf4e"
'''

Any insites to why I'm getting the error when attempting to do it when batching with the the following url field in the request:

'''
"url": "/sites/{xxxxx.sharepoint.com,a2460b71-0904-4476-a18b-ce6ac77a1287,e0f4fd7b-
b513-4d13-be7d-0f0e0b3baf4e}/lists/{8ea8962a-e198-4a1b-a825-6da777887948}/items"
'''

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove curly brackets from `url`.

```
{
"requests": [
    {
        "id": "1",
        "method": "GET",
        "url": "/sites/xxxxxx.sharepoint.com,a2460b71-0904-4476-a18b- 
               ce6ac77a1287,e0f4fd7b-b513-4d13-be7d-0f0e0b3baf4e/lists/8ea8962a- 
               e198-4a1b-a825-6da777887948/items"
    }
  ]
}
```